# Removing title & footer in printing HTML?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, printing

I wanna print some HTML pages, But There are below Title and Footer in each page.(Page Number, Date, Title, Address) 
[image: Printed Page]
How can I do it in Windows XP and Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page setup in ie8 and firefox will allow you to change the settings for header and trailer for all pages printed.

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox, you can use the Page Setup button while in Print Preview to adjust headers and footers.[image]

Comment: Where is Page Setup in Firefox 3 ?

Comment: @Mohammad: File > Page Setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably have a separate style sheet for printer.
like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">`
There you can set the header and footer to display:none
Hope this helps..